# how to check if one element is hidden with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show and hide one div as below:

```
$('#Div1').click(function () {
            if ($("#Div2").hidden) {
                $("#Div2").show(500);
            }
            else {
                $("#Div2").hide(1000);
            }

        });
```

this code does not work.

and i want to hide div2 with clicking on empty sapce of page how can i do that and where is my code is wrong?

Comment: @Vipin Soni: The timings are different for show and hide

Comment: Just put your title in google: `how to check if one element is hide with jquery` THX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hidden` is not a property of a jQuery object. Try `is(':hidden')`

```
  $('#Div1').click(function () {
        if ($("#Div2").is(':hidden')) {
            $("#Div2").show(500);
        }
        else {
            $("#Div2").hide(1000);
        }

  });
```

If the timings were the same you could simply use `toggle()` which does `hide` or `show` based on the current visibility.

```
  $('#Div1').click(function () {
       $("#Div2").stop().toggle(500);
  });
```

And as @A. Wolff suggests, to allow for multiple clicks, use `stop` as well to halt any existing animation in progress:

```
  $('#Div1').click(function () {
        if ($("#Div2").stop().is(':hidden')) {
            $("#Div2").show(500);
        }
        else {
            $("#Div2").hide(1000);
        }
  });
```

**Part 2:**

To hide the div when you click anywhere else on the page, listen for click on `document`:

e.g.

```
 $(document).click(function(){
     $("#Div2").stop().hide(1000);
 });
```

for this to work properly though, you cannot allow the click on div1 to propagate to document so change the first part to also use `stopPropagation()` on the first event argument:

```
  $('#Div1').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();       // stop click propagating to document click handler
        if ($("#Div2").is(':hidden')) {
            $("#Div2").show(500);
        }
        else {
            $("#Div2").hide(1000);
        }
  });
```

Comment: Regarding the second one using toggle(), you should `stop()` animation to handle mutliple click on `#Div1`

Comment: tanks.How hide div with clicking on page?

Comment: @mohsen: Added an example